# Linqpad 5 'Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version 2.0.0.0'

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6, linqpad

Trying to add a connection to my database with licensed version of LinqPad 5 through EF6.

I selected my app's .dll, and then get the error:

> Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core,
>   Version 2.0.0.0

My app has a reference to Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core and the properties pane shows Version: 2.0.0.0

But the reference's path is packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll - could that be the problem?